# Debugging websockets in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, debugging, websocket, wireshark

I'd like to inspect/debug the network traffic of a NodeJS application that uses websockets. I didn't see an obvious way to redirect the application's websocket traffic through a proxy like Fiddler (the application uses the [ws package](http://einaros.github.io/ws/)). Is Wireshark my only option? It's a pain to have to drill down through the trees to find the unmasked text for each packet. Using "[Follow TCP Stream](http://www.notshabby.net/2012/09/wireshark-dissecting-websocket-conversations/)" is almost what I want, but the outgoing text is masked, and it would be nice to have a timestamp adjacent to each message.

Comment: Do you have access to the client?  Chrome's dev tools contain a useful view that sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: The application runs in NodeJS on both the client and server sides, i.e. not in a browser. I'd love to use Chrome's dev tools if I could, but AFAIK you can't execute Node inside Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Although long time passed for this question, but it seems Microsoft's Visual Studio Code has an answer to this question. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging. May help someone someday.